# Java (JNA) - can't find function in DLL (C++) library

Tags: java, dll, jna

I am new in Java, searched for this question in google and stackoverflow, found some posts, but still I can't understand.

I want to use DLL libary (C++) methods from Java. I use JNA for this purpose. JNA found my library but it can't find my method: 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'LoadCurrentData': The specified procedure could not be found.`

My code:

```
package javaapplication1;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    public interface LibPro extends Library {
        LibPro INSTANCE = (LibPro) Native.loadLibrary(
            (Platform.isWindows() ? "LibPro" : "LibProLinuxPort"), LibPro.class);

        public  short LoadCurrentData();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      LibPro sdll = LibPro.INSTANCE;
      sdll.LoadCurrentData();  // call of void function
    }
 }
```

I looked in my DLL with Depency Walker Tool and saw that my function name has prefix and suffix - it looks like `_LoadCurrentData@0`

Thanks for response!

P.S. I found good example which works http://tutortutor.ca/cgi-bin/makepage.cgi?/articles/rjna (Listing 6).

Comment: What does LibPro do? There might be a (really quick) pure java way to achieve this without having to delve into the nightmarish native library implementation.

Comment: Without LibPro I have to deal with nightmarish byte data parsing and crc checks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that you need to apply correct name mapper, as you noticed function name got mangled, you need to register `CallMapper` that will implement the same mangling as your compiler.

Here is a revelant entry [from JNA homepage](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#my-library-mapping-causes-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror):

> Use a dump utility to examine the names of your exported functions to make sure they match (nm on linux, depends on Windows). On Windows, if the functions have a suffix of the form "@NN", you need to pass a StdCallFunctionMapper as an option when initializing your library interface. In general, you can use a function mapper (FunctionMapper) to change the name of the looked-up method, or an invocation mapper (InvocationMapper) for more extensive control over the method invocation.

Here is a possibly revelant question: [renaming DLL functions in JNA using StdCallFunctionMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518131/renaming-dll-functions-in-jna-using-stdcallfunctionmapper)

Comment: In addition, you need to extend `StdCallLibrary` (instead of `Library`) on Windows, or conditionally pass in `Library.OPTION_CALLING_CONVENTION` with a value of `StdCallLibrary.STDCALL_CONVENTION` when loading on Windows.

Comment: Why it doesn't work if i call method with necessary suffix `_LoadCurrentData()`?

Comment: Because mangled function name is `_LoadCurrentData@0` (notice the `@0`), and function name containing `@` is illegal in Java.

Comment: @technomage Thanks for the tip! Helped a lot. In my case, I didn't even have to write code to distinguish between Windows and other platforms - JNA 4.5.1 with the `StdCallLibrary.FUNCTION_MAPPER` option seems to work on Windows 7 32-bit, Mac OS 10.13.2, Unbuntu Linux 16.04 64-bit. (I didn't try the `StdCallLibrary.STDCALL_CONVENTION`.) See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156055/jna-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found/48443321