# call c++ methods from a dll containing several classes using JNA

Tags: c++, jna

I'm working on a project that creates dll of a cpp module and tries to call some methods from that dll using JNA.

I managed to call static methods by mapping their names (that I get from Dependency Walker) with a clearer one.

My question is, is there a way to avoid getting these weird names with "?" and "@" all around after compilation?

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java (JNA) - can't find function in DLL (C++) library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304530/java-jna-cant-find-function-in-dll-c-library)

Comment: Did you start with a simple [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=jni+c%2B%2B+name+mangling&oq=c%2B%2B+jna+name&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3.4505j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=jna+c%2B%2B+name+mangling)? (the weird names is normally known as "name mangling").

Comment: @crashmstr yes I did, and I know what they're It's just that I'm so pissed off that I didn't want to call it so, sorry!
Thanks for the link! I'll check it and tell you if I got the answer there.

Comment: @crashmstr I think that I wasn't clear enough. I can call static methods by renaming them (mapping). so the answer in the topic you gave can't help me. I'm looking for a way to avoid tottaly  the name mangling if it's possible of course

Comment: Another [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+prevent+name+mangling&oq=C%2B%2B+prevent+na&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2.6096j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) results in [How do I stop name-mangling of my DLL's exported function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467144/how-do-i-stop-name-mangling-of-my-dlls-exported-function)